# How do I make patches like these?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Was wondering how to make patches with effects like these (is it called embroidered?) in Photoshop. Other software are fine too! Always looking to expand my knowledge.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you struggling?  This is **not** a "tutorial on demand" site.

Comment: I've tried making them but I just can't seem to find the right overlays/textures for them and can't seem to make them look as realistic as these.

Comment: I have a receipe. I put it out if you can convince me that you have tried something by yourself and seem to have walked through elementaries  which are needed to understand receipes in short form. So: Show your own attempts , also their construction and tell what's wrong.

Comment: It'd be great if you could do that. Unfortunately, I don't think I can show my attempts here but I've followed multiple tutorials on various platforms (YouTube, forums, etc.) and they all turned out to not be realistic looking. I can show an image I created following the same tutorials [here](https://imgur.com/a/rvYv1) (Imgur album), it just doesn't look as realistic as the images featured above.

Comment: They consist of multiple layers and masks with their own groups for the shadows, patch texture effects with .psb files.

Comment: Try this program: http://www.drawstitch.com/index.php/Products/Embroidery_Effect/Download/

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the linked  (Imgur) patches, know that they do not become better with some easy Photoshop trickery. They already are very fine job! Maybe you can borrow the hairy edge of a real patch and add it.

You have used masked canvas textures and added light and shadow, all well done.  **What's missing?  My opinion**: You need shapes where the pattern is knitted along curved forms. That needs a program, where you can use pattern brushes which put shapes along curves. It's well visible in your images:

[image]

Illustrator accepts vector shapes to be inserted to the brush collection as  pattern brushes. Draw manually or vectorize from a photo a short horizontal knitted pattern with matching ends. When dragged to  the brush collection, you can draw any curve with it.

Vectorized photos are heavy load, I suggest you draw the knitted patterns to keep Illustrator unglogged.

The created shape can be copied and pasted to photoshop and used as the canvas textures. The difference is that fine patterns follow curves.

Affinity Designer allows to use PNG images directly as a brush for vector curves. You do not have the load of vectorized shapes. Unfortunately A.designer still has limited tools to draw the vector shapes. There is no blending to create gradually morphed copies between 2 curves, which I see essential for this as work saver.

To stay in truth, you can have same pattern in different angles in Photoshop and simulate curves with polylines, but that is a hard way to work.

**Finally** a screenshot from Affinity Designer. There's a piece of knitted pattern It's a PNG with transparent background, taken from a photo. It's quite long, but that's good for avoiding repeating looks.  It's inserted to Brushes and applied to a random curve and one A character.

The width (=pattern size) and color are freely adjustable and the curve is still an editable path. I have left a copy of the path visible.

[image]

Comment: Illustrator brushes support images too. scatter, pattern and art brush.